# Can preg_match() (or other php regex function) match a variable number of parenthesized subpatterns?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Suppose I have `'/srv/www/site.com/htdocs/system/application/views/'` and want to test it against a regexp that matches each directory name in the path?

*Something* like this pattern: `'(/[^/])'`
That yields an array with `'srv','www','site.com'...` etc.

PS: the regexp syntax I wrote is just to illustrate, it's not tested and surely wrong, but just to give an idea.

PS2: I know there's `explode()` but let's see if we can do this with a regexp (it's useful for other languages and frameworks which don't have explode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`preg_match_all`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$str = '/srv/www/site.com/htdocs/system/application/views/';

preg_match_all('/\/([^\/]+)/', $str, $matches);

// $matches[0] contains matching strings
// $matches[1] contains first subgroup matches
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => srv
    [1] => www
    [2] => site.com
    [3] => htdocs
    [4] => system
    [5] => application
    [6] => views
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [`preg_split`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for splitting files on regular expressions similar to explode, and then there is [`preg_match_al`l](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) which does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, but you could instead use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to get multiple matches from a regular expression. There is also [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split) which may be more appropriate.